# Like php mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou trabalhando em um sistema de likes (curtidas) mas as coisas estão muito confusas, eu tenho a tabela do Post (O conteúdo a ser curtido) com as seguintes colunas

```
|ID|TITLE|CONTENT|LIKES|
```

Na coluna `LIKES`, sempre que um usuário aperta o botão curtir é adicionado +1 ao numero atual, mas eu preciso salvar cada post que o usuário curtiu, isto é uma tabela para saber quais posts cada usuário curtiu, para alterar o estilo do botão e sinalizar que ele ja curtiu o Post e até mesmo pra que ele possa "descurtir" o post. A principio eu pensei em criar uma tabela com o uma coluna para o ID do usuário e uma coluna para cada Post e definir false para não curtido e true para curtido, mas é claro que isso seria inviável pois são muitos posts, então qual é a melhor maneira de fazer isso!

Comment: Acho que é melhor que você crie uma tabela só de likes em que registra o like de cada usuário e contabilize os likes de cada post a partir do relacionamento de tabelas, senão você não tem como verificar qual usuário curtiu ou não uma publicação.

Comment: Sim, mas como eu faria isso, uma tabela com o id do usuário e os posts que ele curtiu ? para isso eu deveria criar uma coluna para cada post, ou uma tabela para cada post e registrar cada usuário que curtiu! certo ?

Comment: Eu não sei se entendi direito mas se trata de um relacionamento N:N  entre a entidade USUARIO E POST gerando uma nova tabela CURTIDAS que deve conter as chaves estrangeiras que são as primary key das tabelas USUARIOS E POST. Você precisa gerar uma nova tabela nesse caso.

Comment: Você cria duas tabelas e uma relacionada com estas duas onde temos as tabelas usuários e publicações e uma tabela de "likes" que tem as colunas usuario_id e publicação_id pra relacionar as duas tabelas, é um relacionamento NxN simples

Comment: ah, sim acho que entendi!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que queres é uma relação entre tabelas NxN (muitos para muitos), um utilizador pode curtir vários posts, e um post pode ser curtido por vários utilizadores.

O mais convencional é criar uma tabela pivot, ex:

Nome da tabela: `posts_likes`

```
+----+---------+---------+
| id | id_user | id_post |
+----+---------+---------+
|  1 |       1 |       1 | 
|  2 |       2 |       1 |  
|  3 |       1 |       2 | 
+----+---------+---------+
```

Desta maneira podes verificar se um determinado utilizador curtiu um certo post:

SQL, ex:

```
SELECT * FROM `posts_likes` WHERE `id_user`= 10 AND `id_post` = 103;
```

Se alguma linha for retornada significa, neste caso, que o utilizador cujo `id = 10` curtiu o post cujo `id = 103`, e aí poderás alterar o estilo do botão e sinalizar que ele ja curtiu o Post.

Comment: Execelente Resposta! +1

Comment: @RafaelSalomão obgado. Li agora os comentários, basicamente foi o que disseste também

Comment: Perfeito, vou colocar em pratica, muito obrigado!

Comment: de nada @FoX, ainda bem